# Vertical LInes Displayed In Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since reinstalling Visual Studio Code a few days ago, I have two vertical lines displayed in my editor.  I've not seen this before, I'm not sure what it represents, and I can't figure out how to turn it off.

[image]

Comment: do you have them defined in your `settings.json`, disable all extensions to see if they are the cause

Comment: These look like indicator lines for 80 and/or 120 characters per line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `settings.json`

```
"editor.rulers": [
     80
],
```

Change this number to null

```
"editor.rulers": [],
```

More on rulers here: [vs-code-vertical-rulers](https://dev.to/brad_beggs/vs-code-vertical-rulers-for-prettier-code-3gp3)